# Access Extbase ObjectStorage from Fluid for loop chaos (how to avoid nested loops)

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

**update 31.01.**

Meanwhile I made a new test Ext as written on Marcels webpage:
http://lbrmedia.net/codebase/Eintrag/extbase-bidirektionale-mm-relation/

I have the same Issue with that.

The goal ist that a Feuser (logged-in) can see all available clients and pick his favorites. So every Feuser can have many clients and each client can be picked by many Feusers. The table relations are correct. In the backend I can see and update the relations on every side (clients can pick Feusers from the list and vice versa.

Please find all the data needed in my Gist:
https://gist.github.com/metaxos/91622c536588d0aa8440

The ZIP of the extension can be found here: http://www.filedropper.com/testmm000201501311251

### **initial question**

For a small Extbase extension. I have a m:n connection between Feusers and Clients. Each Feuser can have multiple clients associated. I have build the relation with Extension Builder and in the backend everything works as needed.

In my frontend plugin I can also add clients to my feuser with attach (this works).

Every Feuser can see all clients (this works). In the for loop of all clients I want to show an icon if the client is associated with the feuser (this works).

**But** how can i avoid the inner for loop (see below)?

```
<f:for each="{feusers.clients}" as="singleClient">
```

**Feusers model**:

```
/**
 * Clients
 *
 * @lazy
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<Exapoint\Exaibbrplus\Domain\Model\Clients>
 */
protected $clients;

/**
  * __construct
  */
public function __construct() {
    $this->initStorageObjects();
}

/**
 * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function initStorageObjects() {
    $this->clients = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}

/**
 * Returns the clients
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Exapoint\Exaibbrplus\Domain\Model\Clients> $clients
 */
public function getClients() {
    return $this->clients;
}
```

**List.html**:

```
<f:for each="{clients}" as="client">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <f:for each="{feusers.clients}" as="singleClient">
                <f:if condition="{client.identifier}=={singleClient.identifier}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </f:if>
            </f:for>
        </td>
    </tr>
</f:for>
```

Relation:
[image]

Here's the dump of my clients of feusers:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if a FrontendUser can have n clients, but a client can have only one FrontendUser, you should have used an 1:n relation.

Somehow, your code is very distracting: You iterate through `{feusers.clients}`, but you can only do that if `feusers` is in fact not an ObjectStorage of FrontendUsers, but a single FrontendUser. Maybe you could post more of your setup.

A suggest you add a transient property to your `Clients` model, e.g.

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 * @transient
 */
protected $isChildOfAuthenticatedUser`
```

For this property you create a getter. The getter compares if the currently authenticated user is identical to the parent user of the client. In the example I'm assuming that a `Client` only has one parent/`FrontendUser`:

```
/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function $isChildOfAuthenticatedUser {
  if ((int)$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid'] === $this->frontendUser->getUid()) {
      return TRUE;
  } else {
      return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Then, in your Fluid template, you just need to check on that transient property:

```
<f:if condition="{client.isChildOfAuthenticatedUser}">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</f:if>
```

Keep in mind to add some additional check if the data is also to be displayed if no user is authenticated.

Comment: A Feuser can have multiple clients. A single client can also have multiple Feuser. Imagine Feuser is a doctor. The doctor has many clients and clients can have more than one doctor (one for the eyes one for the flue, etc.).

Each Feuser who is logged in can "pic" his clients, the idea was to show them all clients at all and indicate them with a icon that client 15 and client 34 are already connected with them, if not give them the possibility to attach the list entry (client) to them (Feuser).

Comment: regarding displayed data, it's only for logged-in users, nothing public. Do you mean because of the access to feusers data?

Comment: hi, i added infos in my previous post. sorry i'm unexperienced and I don't want to make it wrong here... should I remove the old question and do a new one? How should I proceed?

Comment: No, it's fine to just edit the post. I will get back to you later or tomorrow.